# Unable to print json object value in ionic2 ts file

Tags: typescript

In this code, i call 'postRequest()' function. This function is calling from button in login.html In login.html, there is one field for mobile number and i pass this mobile number to service url for validation and when it validate postRequest() function is call for getting sid, status, otp. I get this values in 'result' variable as shown in code. But when i print manually like 'result.status', it shows undefined whereas status is 100 if condition true else status is 101.

```
postRequest() {

let postUrl = "http url";

let postParams = {
  mobile_input: this.mobile_number

}

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

  this.http.post(postUrl, postParams, options)
    .subscribe(data => {


      let result =  data['_body'];  
      console.log(result);          //{"status":"100","otp":8995,"sid":"2"}
      console.log(result.status);   //undefined

      if (result.status == "100") {

        console.log(this.mobile_number);
        this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage, {
        mobilePassed: this.mobile_number
        })


      } /*else {
        console.log("Invalid number");
      }*/

    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse JSON string to object first like `let res = JSON.parse(result);` and then you can access status like `res.status`.

Hope this helps